# auxiliaries before homogeneous members of the sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis, perfect-aspect

Is it possible to omit the second auxiliary in this sentence:

"She has followed our advice and (has) started..."

P.S. I have always thought it is as the verbs to follow and to start refer to one and the same subject and hence are homogeneous members of the sentence. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the "has" distributes over both verbs. However, because of the "and", the sentence is not completely clear as to whether "our advice" was to "start..[x]" or to do (or quit doing) something else. If the former, I would consider replacing "and started" with "by starting" .